# Using Lua to parse a txt file and output a table

Tags: parsing, lua

I'm new to Lua and need some help parsing a text file and outputting the data into a table format.

The text file is set up in columns representing 
`GroupID` `IndividualID` `Name` `Status` and contains the following:

```
100 1 AAA 1
100 2 BBB 2
100 3 CCC 0
200 4 DDD 1
200 5 EEE 1
```

I'd like the output to appear as:

```
100 2
200 2
```

Where the 2nd columns is a totally tally for non-zero status. Here is my code so far:

```
function readText ("sample.txt")
     local file = io.open("sample.text", "r")
          if file then
          for line in file:lines() do
               local group, individual, name, status = line:split(" ")
                    local count = 0
                    if status ~= "0" then count = count + 1
                            table.insert (group, count)
                    print (group, count)
     end
     file:close()
 else
 end
end
```

In order to output the count for the 2nd `GroupID`, would I need to use

```
if group ~= group then 
table.insert (group, count)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this inner loop:

```
local last=nil
local count=0
for line in ifile:lines() do
    local group,status=line:match("^(%S+)%s.*%s(%S+)$")
    if group~=last then
        if count>0 then
            print(last,count)
        end
        count=0
        last=group
    end
    if status~="0" then
        count=count+1
    end
end
if count>0 then
    print(last,count)
end
```